# tuckey urlrewrite facebook crawler user agent detect

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-agent, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have an angular app, I trying to include facebook og with every links of my app.
Since angular render's pages on client side I have used technique as suggested in this blog- https://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app

I am facing issue in user-detection part of it. On 9th July, 17 code mentioned below as working fine, not sure why its not working good.

```
    <rule>
        <condition name="user-agent" next="or">facebookexternalhit/1.1</condition>
        <condition name="user-agent" next="or">Facebot</condition>
        <condition name="user-agent">Twitterbot/*</condition>
        <from>/wall/*</from>
        <set name="postUrl">$1</set>
        <to>/crawler-index.jsp</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/wall/*</from>
        <to>/index.jsp</to>
    </rule>
```

**How to detect facebook crawler?**

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I don’t know how this tucker stuff works, but since you used `Twitterbot/*` I’d assume it looks for exact matches, unless you use a wildcard such as `*`? In that case, you will need one for the FB scraper, too, because the full user agent it sends is not just `facebookexternalhit/1.1`, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1748179212062572

Comment: @CBore: You answer worked, please answer the question and I will give you right mark, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how this tucker stuff works, but since you used `Twitterbot/*` I’d assume it looks for exact matches, unless you use a wildcard such as `*`

In that case, you will need one for the FB scraper, too, because the full user agent it sends is not just `facebookexternalhit/1.1`, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1748179212062572

(You could also match the exact user agent string - but with something like `facebookexternalhit/*` you’re probably better off when Facebook releases a “version update” for their scraper at some point in the future.)